# Divi Theme woocommerce gallery - more images per page

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming, divi

I would like to change the default number of photos per page that is displayed in the woocommerce gallery of the product in Divi Theme. Currently default option is 4 photos per page.

[currently - only 4 images per page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfoMw.jpg)

How can i make 2 rows of photos i mean 8 photos per page in product gallery?

[woocommerce divi gallery - no option to set for example 8 images per page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4paGa.png)

I'd like to add a second row of photos in the product gallery. I made layout in product theme builder and there is no option like in classic gallery module. Maybe any snipped in fuctions.php should work. I am using child theme for divi.

[classsic gallery in divi - here is option to set how many images per page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EFcK1.png)

I found there is in file Divi\includes\builder\module\Gallery.php default post number option (i changed it and it works, but i dont know how to overwrite it in child theme)

[code for default gallery option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4HzK.jpg)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Ask DIVI Support if there is any hook to filter the no of images shown in the product gallery or read the plugin code and find out the filter for this kind of customization.